# Nullable DateTime?

Tags: c#, nullable

how to create setter and getter Properties for nullable datetime.
for example:

```
private DateTime mTimeStamp;

public DateTime TimeStamp
{
      get { return mTimeStamp; }
      set { mTimeStamp = value; }
}
```

Does nullable attributes support setter and getter or have i to declare it public?

```
private DateTime? mTimeStamp;

public DateTime TimeStamp
{

}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can just do this instead:

```
public DateTime? TimeStamp { get; set; }
```

If you were having trouble with the compiler it's probably because you only changed one of the associated parts - either the `private` member variable or the property's data type. They need to match, of course, and auto-properties handles that for you nicely.

**EDIT** Just to further clarify, `DateTime?` is not merely decorated with an `?` attribute - it's *entirely* different from `DateTime`. `DateTime?` is shorthand for `Nullable<DateTime>`, which is a generic ([`Nullable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx)) that provides nullable support to non-reference types by wrapping the generic parameter `T`, which is a `struct`.

Comment: +1 for "they need to match" and auto properties handling that nicely.

Answer (score 3):

You can create the property in the same way as a normal `DateTime` property:

```
public DateTime? TimeStamp { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to make a DateTime nullable in this way:

```
private DateTime? mTimeStamp;

public DateTime? TimeStamp
{
      get { return mTimeStamp; }
      set { mTimeStamp = value; }
}
```

You can use this modifier on other types as well.  Read up here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s%28v=VS.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

A nullable DateTime is a discrete type from a regular DateTime and can be used like any other type.  So your code would be:

```
private DateTime? mTimeStamp;

public DateTime? TimeStamp
{
      get { return mTimeStamp; }
      set { mTimeStamp = value; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's the same as non-nullable:

`public DateTime? TimeStamp { get; set; }`

You can replace `DateTime` with `DateTime?` in your top sample code (looks like code is missing at the bottom of your post).

Answer (score 2):

```
private DateTime? mTimeStamp;

public DateTime? TimeStamp
{
  get { return mTimeStamp; }
  set { mTimeStamp = value; }
}
```

or, if you are using .net 3.0+

```
public DateTime? TimeStamp {get;set;}
```