# Converting to Nullable Type without extra method

Tags: c#, type-conversion, nullable

Is writing something like this kosher?  Or are there problems that may arise?

```
private DateTime? getDate(object date)
{
    return date != null ? Convert.ToDateTime(date) : (DateTime?)null;
}
```

I've seen a lot of questions asking a similar question, but the answer is always given an extension method that does the job of converting, I was wondering if I could skip that step and write like this, or is there some edge case I am not accounting for?

Also I'm using DateTime in the example, but I would think this could work for any nullable type.

Comment: I'm assuming you have accounted for InvalidCastException or FormatException outside of this method? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ky38w316.aspx - If so - seems ok to me!

Comment: @Jay In my particular case it is coming from a date field in a database, so it will be either a valid date or null, I was just going to do this down the line of things I get back so I preserve null for each value, or convert it to the proper datetype.

Comment: Why are you taking an object as a parameter when you expect a DateTime to get passed in?  If you want to make it more generic, you might be able to use a method with the following signature (I haven't verified this): private Nullable<T> getNullable<T>(T object).  There is a generic conversion method you can use inside the method.  I'm pretty sure this is similar to the extension method examples I've seen, but it isn't an extension method, which is what you requested.

Comment: @dustmouse the code is taken out of context, I don't actually have a method called getDate it was just a fast way to demonstrate the problem I was wondering about, really I am converting from a object from within a DataRow and I just want to preserve it's null state if that is what it is.  I probably should have phrased the question a little differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `?` is a type of `Nullable<T>`, it is completely fine and 'kosher' as long as you are aware of the actual return type. It is as if you are writing the method as:

```
private Nullable<DateTime> getDate(object date)
{
   ...
}
```

As long as you are aware the below won't work because the return types will differ:

`DateTime myDateTimeVariable = getdate(someObject);` because it's a type conversion problem.

You can see this for another explaination: [Nullable DateTime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839787/nullable-datetime)

Comment: Yeah it is being stored into something of datatype `datetime?` and since it is coming from a date database field it should either be a valid date or a null.  I think this answers my question.